# All directed paths between any two vertices have the same length

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Is there a term for the condition that, given some directed graph $G = (V, E)$, for all $v, w \in V$ every directed path from $v$ to $w$ has the same length as every other?

Comment: In thinking about what @EricWofsey suggested, it occurred to me that the condition described forces the directed graph to be acyclic (and this tends to support his idea).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're describing a [graded poset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_poset) and you can use the term "graded graph".

Eric's condition is correct and the homomorphism is usually denoted $\rho: V \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ where $(x,y) \in E \implies \rho(y) = \rho(x) + 1$

$\rho$ is called a rank function and is sometimes written $|x|$.

Comment: True if $G$ is finite, but if infinite graphs are allowed, you could have $V=\Bbb Z$ and $E=\{\langle n,n+1\rangle:n\in\Bbb Z\}$, which isn’t a graded graph. (I don’t know whether the OP wants to consider infinite graphs.)

Comment: Good point. I've just found a paper that refers to an "infinite $\mathbb{Z}$-graded graph," but this doesn't seem to be a typical term. Perhaps it can be useful for the OP nonetheless.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Why doesn't that satisfy the definition of a graded graph?  EDIT: Never mind, I see that gradings on posets are required to be nonnegative, which explains it.